# Get Windows Version String C++

Tags: c++, windows

How can I get the windows version name in a string, e.g. "Windows 8.1, version 6.3.9600 - x64 (64 bit)" in C++, without using a library that is not included in windows. I have looked at getCurrentVersion and done countless searches for a solution, but have found nothing.

Comment: [This one perhaps?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724833(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: How about this one: http://www.naughter.com/dtwinver.html

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could obtain the information from the [Win32_OperatingSystem class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I think the Description field might do what you want. For information on how to use WMI in C++ see [Example: Getting WMI Data from the Local Computer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There's a detailed discussion of this [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724429%28VS.85%29.aspx):

"To obtain the full version number for the operating system, call the `GetFileVersionInfo` function on one of the system DLLs, such as Kernel32.dll, then call `VerQueryValue` to obtain the `\\StringFileInfo\\<lang><codepage>\\ProductVersion` subblock of the file version information."

Comment: I am trying to avoid if cases as they are not forwards-compatible with new versions of windows. For example, say windows 9 comes out, and I forget to update this par of my program. The program will still report windows 8. Note: I do think a simple list of version numbers and is names would work

Comment: @amo, that quote applies to the version **number**, not the version **string**.

Comment: @user3053430: starting with Windows 8.1, you have to include a manifest that explicitly states which Windows versions your app supports. When Windows 9 comes out, if your manifest does not include 9.0 then `GetVersion/Ex()` will report 8.1 instead, or 8.0 if your manifest does not include 8.1. So you have to update your manifest for each new Windows release, so you can update your `if` statements at the same time. How's that for "forward compatible".

Comment: Actually that's even worse but I think I'll just go with a 'getos' function in a separate DLL that I can update whenever a new version of windows comes out. By "forwards compatible" I meant I won't have to update it when a new version of windows comes out, and it will still say the same thing. But, I guess there's no avoiding this.

Comment: versionhelpers.h - No such file or directory. I am using angle brackets like I should, but gcc can't find the header file.